# Spring AOP Usage

Tags: spring, logging, aop, spring-aop

I am thinking of moving all my Slf4j logging to replace with Spring AOP. 
But now I have some questions on how to use Spring AOP in the following scenarios. 
I could see that we can use it to print general method trace logs and some arguments as well. 
Lets say a situation like this.

```
public void methodTest(User object) {
    Integer number = object.getValue();
    List<Param> params = object.getParams();
    if((number == null || number < 1000 || number > 10000)) {
            LOGGER.error("Invalid Number- " + number);
            //May not throw below exception. Just want to log and continue.  
            //throw new Exception(ErrorCode.INVALID_USER_NUMBER); 

        } else if (number == 10000) {
            if(params != null && params.size() > 0) {
                LOGGER.error("No params supported for number "+number);
                throw new Exception(ErrorCode.INVALID_SCALE);
            }
            return;
        }

        if(number >= 1000 && number < 10000 && (params == null || params.size() == 0)) {
            LOGGER.error("Not all params available");
            throw new Exception(ErrorCode.INVALID_PARAM);
        }

}
```

How can we adapt Spring AOP in this case?  I have different log statements and values to print based on different logic.

---

Update: Writing our log statements based on ErrorCode what we received in Aspect looks good?
If we have same error code in few of the scenarios, log statements could be different rt. Is it possible to handle that as well?
Lastly, instead of error scenarios if I have debug statements to be used based on different conditions, do we get the control in Aspect?

Answer (score 0):

Create an Aspect class where you define all your pointcuts and advices:

```
    @Aspect
    @Component
    public class Foo {     
      @Pointcut("execution(* com.example.ClassName.methodName(..))")
      private void exampleMethod() {}

      @Before("exampleMethod()")
      public void exampleAdvice() {
        //your logging implementation
      }
   }
```

here you can find more examples:
https://javamondays.com/spring-aop-beginners-guide/